# assigned ips to my custom nameservers, however still the nameservers showing with "No IP"

Tags: nameserver

I went to  Main >> Server Configuration >> Basic cPanel & WHM Setup and correctly assigned the IPs to my 2 custom nameservers. After that (on same screen) I created A records also for the nameservers, and finally clicked on "Save Changes".

However when I go to Main >> Networking Setup >> Nameserver IPs, the 2 nameservers are shown, but under IP Address field, the value shown is "No IP".

What do I do to ensure that IPs are correctly assigned to my nameservers?

Comment: I wonder if it's looking for the "glue records" your domain registrar has for your nameservers.  Does `whois` list your nameservers' IP addresses for your domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to register your name servers with the domain registrar. This creates so-called "glue records", which will then show up in your domain registration details. Some domain registrars will require a working DNS setup for the domain before they activate the glue records, so all your preparations so far are correct, you just need to make the final step.

Once the domain updates have propagated around the world, name resolution for your domain should work.

Comment: +1 for the most part, except that DNS doesn't propagate.

Comment: thanks, i created glue records and now it works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You should edit the following file:

```
/etc/nameserverips
```

Once you have added the correct entries, which are in the format

```
1.2.3.4=ns1.domain.com
1.2.3.5=ns2.domain.com
```

you should then load the Nameserver IPs option in WHM, these should then show up with IPs.